# Pointing a domain-name to my local RaspberryPi running Raspbian Wheezy

Tags: apache2, dns, raspberrypi

[I hope this is the right StackExchange site for this question. It is about Ubuntu, but also about servers/networking.]

I have a RaspberryPi running Apache on my local network. I forwarded port 80, so it is now accessible from outside my network through my external IP-address.

I have a domain-name with a Dutch registrar which I want to point to my Pi. This registrar requires me to enter at least 2 nameservers. Currently I have it set to ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com and ns3.digitalocean.com.

I have tried to enter my external IP-address for both nameserver 1 and 2, but this is not accepted.

I found some tutorial on how to point a local domain-name to the Pi, but that is not what I want, since it only works from my laptop.

I hope some of you have a suggestion for mo on where to start or how to get the DNS's for my Pi and how to connect it to my domain-name.

Comment: This is more of a IP forwarding problem and i don't understand what you mean by `point a local domain-name to the Pi`, if that means resolve then i understand.

Comment: Do you have public (as in accessible from the Internet) IP address that you can use?

Comment: This is more of networking and web related... Nothing to do with Ubuntu at all. Maybe this will fit in either Serverfault or probably the best is Unix/Linux stack..

Comment: @AzkerM I had already posted it to ServerFault, but they downvoted it because it was not the right community for this. That is why I tried it here instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point out that there are two different paths there. First hand you have a static IP, second you are unlucky and you IP is dynamic.

If your IP is static then the problem is quiet simple :

-> Go to your registrar website (where you bought your domain)
  -> Find out how to EDIT your DNS ZONE
  -> Add a new "A" record (I guess A stands for address)
    -> this requires 3 bits of information usually : a name or prefix (that thing before the dot like the www in www.yourdomain.com), an IP (that RPi IP ) and a TTL which is a duration expressed in seconds (3600 could be a fair value). This TTL represents how long the clients will keep this in their cache before asking again to your server.

If you have a dynamic IP then it gets a bit more complex, you need to set-up somthing to update your DNS zone every time you change IP. There are many solution to do that, things like no-ip.org, or dyndns... These are the 2 I know of. They work but I don't think they are opensource, AND you rely on yet another third party. You can achieve the same goal by using the dnssec and nsupdate to update your zone yourself. [Here is a good tutorial on howto do that.](http://linux.yyz.us/nsupdate/)

You should definitely read some documentation about DNS, just so you get the correct terminology and a general understanding of how it works. [Here is some.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-dns-terminology-components-and-concepts)

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Look into CloudFlare. You would point your name servers to that then fill in your IP address into CloudFlare and that should work. Plus you'll get Ddos protection and other good services!

https://www.cloudflare.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to add a host record to your zone file on Digital Ocean's nameserver. This record would map the domain to your publicly accessible IP address.

I recommend following the [community](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean#step-three) page from the registrar, paying attention to the mention of A records for IPv4, or AAAA records if using IPv6.

From the sound of it you want to leave the nameserver assignments (ns1,  ns2) as they are.

Comment: No, I don't want to have anything to do with DigitalOcean.